# Multihomed server

Tags: windows-server-2019, multi-homed

I have a server with 4 nic cards. I configured them to be on the same network. Ex: 10.10.1,1, 10.10.1.3, 10.10.1.5, 10.10.1.7. Will I need to configure a default gateway on all? Meaning, if I have set the default gateway on 10.10.1.1 to 10.10.1.1 do I have to set the other nics to the same or leave them blank?

Comment: Why do you want four NICs? What problem is solved by using 4 NICs?

Answer (score 0):

> Will I need to configure a default gateway on all?

A DEFAULT gateway is the DEFAULT gateway to be used when no other route is used. What sense would it make to have 4 of them? Do all 4 networks point ultimatels even to the internet?

> Meaning, if I have set the default gateway on 10.10.1.1 to 10.10.1.1 do I
> have to set the other nics to the same or leave them blank?

THAT makes more sense. You put the default gateway where it makes sense (i.e. the network care where it is routed) and leave the entry for the other nic's empty.

Answer (score 0):

When more than one network adapters is connected to the same network, you only need to set default gateway on one of them. Setting same gateway address on different NICs might create issues.

Also, you might want to consider having 4 IP addressed assigned to a single NIC, unless you have some specific requirements.